# Unable to create a flutter project on Android studio

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, group-policy

I am trying to create a new flutter project on Andriod Studio but the following error is shown:

C:\Users\cvaa4\flutter\bin\flutter.bat **doctor --verbose**

**This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator.**

Process finished with exit code 1

Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Try to install flutter in a different location(directories that might not require elevated access).

Comment: it didn't work, I need to access that group policy but I couldn't find it yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **windows user** has not permision to change(create) files in `C:\Users\..`. you should have `Admin` user in windows.

Comment: it didn't work, I need to access that group policy but I couldn't find it yet!

Comment: [try this]( https://www.minitool.com/news/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy.html)